# Pthreads - out of memory?

Tags: c, linux, unix, pthreads, stack-overflow

I am programming something in C that creates a lot of Pthreads in Linux.

When I run the program with a low amount of threads it works, but once I make it create around 1000 threads it gives errors. Now the `errno` flag is set, but I want to know which one of the problems caused it. `EAGAIN`, `EINVAL`, `ELEMULTITHREADFORK`, or `ENOMEM`.

Is there any way that I can find out if it is one of these errors, and, if yes, which one it is?

Comment: 1000 threads == fix your design.

Comment: I know this is kind of off topic, but do you need to create that many threads? Would it be possible to implement your design using a thread pool (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with 1000 or even 100000 threads. A good implementation can handle them just fine.

Comment: 1000 threads == buy a larger computer and/or try a different OS.

Comment: Everyone's missing the point that OP is simply running out of virtual address space due to glibc's ridiculous default stack size.

Answer (score 8):

I believe what you're looking for is the `pthread_attr_setstacksize` function. By default, glibc reserves 2MB, 8MB, or 10MB or memory for each thread's stack. At this rate you'll quickly exhaust the virtual address space on a 32-bit machine, and quickly exhaust the commit charge even on 64-bit machines.

```
pthread_t td;
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, 32768);
pthread_create(&td, &attr, start_function, start_art);
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
```

This code is over-simplified; naturally you may want to check for failure on some of these calls. Actually that's what your question was originally about. `pthread_*` functions almost all **return the error code as their return value** rather than in `errno`, so `errno` cannot be used to inspect the result, and `perror` will not work unless you assign the return value to `errno`. Instead, do something like:

```
result = pthread_create(&td, &attr, start_function, start_art);
switch (result) {
case EINVAL: /* ... */
case EAGAIN: /* ... */
/* etc. */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`perror()` should do the trick.

Do `man 3 perror` on your linux system.

Comment: Yes, and if you've just printed out the errno, thus are left with something like "22" then look at the `/usr/include/*errno.h` files for the defines.  On most Linux systems you're looking for `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for cheesy testing:

```
int ret;
pthread_t tid;

if ((ret = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, startfunc, NULL)) != 0)
{
    errno = ret;
    perror("pthread_create");
}
```

R is correct that the default stack size is going to chew up memory with that many threads.